# How to zoom out on an object with glTranslatef?

Tags: c++, opengl

I'm trying to zoom out from a polygon with glTranslatef. However, whatever numbers I put in Z (trying to zoom out) inside glTranslatef function, it remains a black window. Here is code:

```
        glClearColor (0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
        glClear (GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        glPushMatrix ();
        glTranslatef(0, 0, 0.9f); //Here I'm translating
        glBegin (GL_POLYGON);
        glColor3f(100, 100, 0); glVertex2f(-1.0f, -1.0f);
        glColor3f(100, 0, 100); glVertex2f(-1.0f, 1.0f);
        glColor3f(25, 25, 25); glVertex2f(1.0f, 1.0f);
        glColor3f(100, 50, 90); glVertex2f(1.0f, -1.0f);
        glEnd ();
        glPopMatrix ();

        SwapBuffers (hDC);
        Sleep (1);
```

I tried with following numbers in Z:
0.9 (works)
-0.9 (works)
1.1 (works not)
-1.1 (works not)

Do I need some other code for this or I'm doing it wrong?

Comment: This depends on your other matrices setup, and the other code you're using.

Comment: And don't use GL_POLYGON.

Comment: or don't use legacy openGL at all especially if you are just learning

Comment: You need to set up your volumetric view, with glOrtho or gluPerspective

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you haven't specified a projection matrix then the standard one will be an orthographic (non-perspective) projection with `left-right` `top-bottom` and `near-far` all being `-1,1`.

So translating outside that will make the vertices not draw at all.

Answer (score 1):

The reason this does nothing is because you have no transformation matrices setup.

Right now you are drawing in a coordinate space known as Normalized Device Coordinates, which has the viewing volume encompass the range [**-1.0**, **1.0**] in all directions. Any point existing outside that range is clipped.

Vertices specified with `glVertex2f (...)` are implicitly placed at `z=0.0` and translating more than **1.0** unit along the Z-axis will push your vertices outside the viewing volume. This is why **-1.1** and **1.1** fail, while **0.9** and **-0.9** work fine.

Even if you translate to a position within the viewing volume, without a perspective projection, translating something along the Z-axis is not going to change its size. The only thing that will happen is that eventually the object will be translated far enough that it is clipped and suddenly disappears (which you already experienced with values **> 1.0** or **< -1.0**).